# HTML Form Submission + Google Client Client API Sign-in

Tags: php, google-client-login

I am working on a client code, where a user fills a form titled page1.php having around 8 fields, and after filling those fields he reaches the Google Login API page titled page2.php.

**page1.php**

```
<form id="p1" action="page2.php" method="post">
Name: <input name="ab" required>
Age: <input name='cd' type="number">

....
.....
<button align='center' type='submit'>Submit</button> 
</form>
```

This page2.php shows the users non-editable text values he filled in page1.php, & at the bottom it has the "Sign-in-with-Google Credentials" button/image.

**page2.php**

```
//Get values using $_POST['ab'] & display:
You've filled following values:
Name: Mac
Age: 32
.....
.....
//An image button for Google Signin
<a href='".$client->createAuthUrl()."'><img src='images/google-signin-button-small.png' alt='Google Login'></img></a>
```

The requirement is that clicking that button/image should trigger the standard Google user authentication through the Google Client API and ADDITIONALLY it should submit the earlier form filled field values into the next HTML page (say pagesubmit.php) using POST method (basically submit to a database). Single button click to trigger two actions.

Since it is client requirement, I don't have much liberty to change the flow.
I am able to get the Google User authentication successfully completed one page2.php using

```
<a href='".$client->createAuthUrl()."'><img src='images/google-signin-button-small.png' alt='Google Login'></img></a>
```

At pagesubmit.php, it correctly captures & shows the name & google email of the user, but the problem is that the form values go missing on this page.

So essentially, I want to have both Google User authentication AND form value submission achieved through that single click on the "Sign-in-with-Google Credentials" button/image.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: When the button's clicked, you should be able to submit the form data to your own PHP script, save the database data, and then redirect the user to the Auth URL. Unless you require that the user is authenticated before saving? It wasn't totally clear. In that case you could maybe put the other values in the Session until authentication is complete.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson - the user needs to be validated & once done the db update should happen. Both the actions expected by 1-click. Creating sessions for Google_Service_Oauth2 service is a very tricky job it seems, so was looking for any possible alternatives to achieve it.

Comment: No I meant store the form data in your own session. Then redirect to the Google auth page. Then when it redirects the browser back with an authenticated user, you can resume and read from the PHP session

Comment: _"but the problem is that the form values go missing on this page."_ - they were never send there in the first place.

Comment: @ADyson - Many thanks! Somehow, PHP sessions just did not strike me bcoz it was client code & i felt restricted. But fortunately, I was able to insert an intermediate PHP page to collect all the form data & then introduce the session which helped achieve the necessary. Thanks a ton. If you want to write that as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it. If you believe this question does not add too much value to SO, let me know if u want me to delete it. Thanks again.

Comment: @CBroe - the issue is that the Google Client API page redirects to itself - the user needs to hit the Sign-in button, pick the desired account (in case of multiple logins), and then the selected one will get displayed on the same page with parameters attached to the same URL. So sending the form values is not useful, as they are lost in the redirect.

Comment: That doesn't contradict what I said. _"the issue is that the Google Client API page redirects to itself"_ - yes, exactly. That means the browser will make a GET request, so _of course_ there is no POST data. The point where it was "lost" was where you redirected somewhere else, to the Google login in this case. If you don't process your POST parameters in the script that they were sent to, then they will always be "lost" once that script ends. That isn't specific to performing a login using Google ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that any form data submitted is lost when you redirect away from your own site, to the Google authentication page.

One solution is to store the form data in the PHP session. So essentially you need to submit the form to your own PHP script. When it's finished processing the form data and storing it, it can issue a redirect header to tell the browser to go to the Google authentication page. Then when that redirects the browser back with an authenticated user, you can resume and read the previously submitted data from the PHP session.